# Should the upvote/downvote tooltips on meta.su be harmonised with meta FAQ?

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface, meta

The upvote/downvote tooltips on meta.superuser are the same as on the main site.
    For the question downvote it is *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* – which isn't really in harmony with [What does voting mean here?](https://meta.superuser.com/faq#vote-differences) in the Meta FAQ, which says

> *Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. On Meta, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness.*

So, should the tooltips on Meta be changed to be in better harmony with the FAQ?
And if so, to what? – "Agree" and "Disagree", or other suggestions?

Comment: +1 Your question shows research effort (and I agree).

Comment: Things I've learned from answers to this so far: **1.** Policy declared on meta.stackoverflow applies to meta.superuser, because Meta Stack Overflow is currently the _de facto_ [Stack Exchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com). – [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) does in fact redirect to meta.stackoverflow.com (but [this is about to change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)).

Answer (score 5):

It's been asked innumerable times on [Meta Stack Overflow] & [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

[Quoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104398/133693) Jeff.

> I don't agree with this request.
>
> While "I agree" and "I disagree" is *one* way that votes can be used
>   on meta, it is not the only way, and I don't want that indoctrinated
>   into users as the "official" meaning of voting on meta.
>
> The current tooltips are correct, and any further subtleties are
>   covered in each meta's faq now:
>
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Were not on stack overflow :-) and I still have trouble voting this down, because it does show research, plus it is a Great Answer, but I still do not agree. If it has a different meaning , or multiple meanings, then it would be helpfull for the tag to show that. I have always thought that from the day it had to be explained.

Comment: @Psycogeek On Meta, you're free to vote down answers/opinions you don't agree with it.

Comment: On all metas besides SO, it doesn't even affect rep.